# Application Deployed using Tomcat, at certain point of time stop and users are not able to login

Tags: java, linux, tomcat7

Here is the issue : My web application is deployed using apache-tomcat-7.0.30. The application worked for about 10 hours, but all of a sudden users are not able to login.

Analysed issues :
1. Could find that no logs are generated in the catalina.out or in any of the logs.
2. The java process is shown as running.
3. Verified the memory usage using TOP command and could find no memory issues.
4.Checked the entire logs for "Out of memory" , "Too many open files", any "Sql Exception" or "Hibernate Exception", but could not find such issues.

In the application we have overridden the log4j and so most of the logs are getting generated in the catalina.out.We had seen issues like "Too many open files" issues when the size of the catalina.out exceeds above 8-9 GB and in rare cases above 3 GB.I would like to know if this is some memory leak issue ? If not will roll out of the catalina.out will rectify the issue ?

**The log4j.properties configuration details is below,**

# Define the root logger with appender file
    log4j.rootLogger = ALL , CONSOLE , LOG_FILE, BHC_TRACES

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = ERROR
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2 = ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO

#Summarised log file.
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.File=../logs/${logfile}.log
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n

#detailed log file that lead to the traces
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.File=../logs/traces/trace.log
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.BHC_TRACES.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n
```

I do not see any specific lines in the logs which tells me or marks the cause of this shutdown.

Can any one help me on how can i analyse further in-order to identify if it the VM level issue or is it because of any recent changes in my code.

Please help me on this. In case of any inputs please let me know..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem and be more specific. what kind of application are you deploying on tomcat?. Does your application do any logging..??. what logging mode have you enabled in you application..?? is there any log appender you are using..?? with out logs it will be difficult to identify the issue.

Comment: @sandieeUpdated my comments above. Please let me know if this details are good enough.

Comment: Can any one help me in providing the possible search keywords to identify the issue in LOGS. Like for example out of memory, exception..etc
This could be help full for me to identify the root cause of the issue.                         

In my case , the Java process was still running, no issues shown related to memory, but the login to application is not working and the logs are not getting generated in the related log files and also in Catalina.out files
                                                              
Has anyone seen such issue?

Comment: When a JVM crashes it normally create dump files. Do you have these files. If you don't specify a path for these files I think they will be in a default place like the tomcat installation folder.

Comment: I dont see a JVM crash in this case, As i could see the java process is still runningand the appllication process is running , when i tried  "ps -ef | grep "application_name".        Here some how the logs are not getting generated and not able to login to the application. Can you please share the dump_files default path and the name.